# Azure media server encoding starts to fail suddenly

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am working with an iphone app that records a video and post it to a site which then uploads it azure media server for encoding.

It has been working flawlessly untill today when azure starts to fail every encoding job.

Do anyone know in which direction I should start to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, send an email to mediaservices@microsoft.com and I'll get someone to look at your issue. Include the Datacenter where you are running, the Media Services account name and some failed JOB IDs. Also include the time when it began for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will do it first thing tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Besiddes the excellent answer of what to do if it actually could be microsoft wrong doing I have to post one myself. It was actually a racing condition that suddenly emerged and I posted only part of the videos byte array and thereby missing informationen leading to failure in encoding. My bad, sorry Azure.